# Cannot create Groove Script on Intellij - Argument for @NotNull parameter

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I am trying to start learning Groovy for perform API calls using ScriptRunner on JIRA. So I am starting from the basics.

My problem is that I cannot even create a  Groovy script using Intellij. At the project creation it am selecting **Groovy** and choosing for project SDK version `16.0.2` and Groovy Library `groovy-3.0.8`

Once the project is created and I try to create the script, the IDE send me the following error message:

`Argument for @NotNull parameter 'rootTypes' of com/intellij/openapi/roots/impl/ProjectFileIndexImpl.isUnderSourceRootOfType must not be null`

Does anyone know why I am getting this error message?

Comment: It's a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275043.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of creating a “Groovy Script”, you can just create a new “File” and name it “filename.groovy”. It will then just create a new groovy script file which you can run.