# Failed to create groovy script in idea

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

After creating a groovy script, an exception message pops up. This problem has troubled me for several days. Does anyone know how to solve it?
[image: The operation steps are shown in the picture]

Comment: It's a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275043

Comment: Please check if the problem reproduces in the latest build from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2021.2+latest+builds .

Comment: The problem still exists in the latest version.                                                          
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 RC (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-212.5080.39, built on August 19, 2021
Licensed to IntelliJ IDEA Evaluator
Expiration date: September 18, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.16 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 750M
Cores: 16

Kotlin: 212-1.5.10-release-IJ5080.39

Comment: I believe this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762599/cannot-create-groove-script-on-intellij-argument-for-notnull-parameter.